# Pandas: Adding Rolling statistics to a dataframe for all the columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to calculate the rolling average, rolling max, rolling min of a data frame and also respect the ID of observation too and store them in a new column. My original data frame have many columns so manually renaming the column is not possible. 
Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
np.random.seed(11) 
date_today = datetime.now()
ndays = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(ndays)], 
               'A': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'B':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .6)

df['ID']=1
df.ID[6:10]=2
df
```

Currently, I am doing the process manually in this form:

```
df[['A_mean','B_mean']]=df.groupby('ID').apply(pd.rolling_mean, 2, min_periods=1).drop('ID',axis=1)
df[['A_max','B_max']]=df.groupby('ID').apply(pd.rolling_max, 2, min_periods=1).drop('ID',axis=1)
```

is there any way to do this with out needing to manually store the new columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```
d = pd.concat({
    df.index[i]: df[['A', 'B']].iloc[max(0, i - 1):i + 1].agg(
        ['min', 'max', 'count', 'mean', 'sum', 'std']).rename(str.title)
    for i in range(1, len(df))
})

d.unstack()

                                   A                                                       B                                              
                                 Min       Max Count      Mean       Sum       Std       Min       Max Count      Mean       Sum       Std
2018-06-21 14:32:32.964218 -0.286073 -0.286073   1.0 -0.286073 -0.286073       NaN -0.886240 -0.475733   2.0 -0.680987 -1.361973  0.290272
2018-06-22 14:32:32.964218 -0.286073 -0.286073   1.0 -0.286073 -0.286073       NaN -0.475733  0.689682   2.0  0.106974  0.213949  0.824073
2018-06-23 14:32:32.964218 -2.653319 -2.653319   1.0 -2.653319 -2.653319       NaN  0.689682  0.689682   1.0  0.689682  0.689682       NaN
2018-06-24 14:32:32.964218 -2.653319 -2.653319   1.0 -2.653319 -2.653319       NaN -1.305549 -1.305549   1.0 -1.305549 -1.305549       NaN
2018-06-25 14:32:32.964218       NaN       NaN   0.0       NaN  0.000000       NaN -1.305549 -1.305549   1.0 -1.305549 -1.305549       NaN
2018-06-26 14:32:32.964218       NaN       NaN   0.0       NaN  0.000000       NaN       NaN       NaN   0.0       NaN  0.000000       NaN
2018-06-27 14:32:32.964218       NaN       NaN   0.0       NaN  0.000000       NaN       NaN       NaN   0.0       NaN  0.000000       NaN
2018-06-28 14:32:32.964218  0.421051  0.421051   1.0  0.421051  0.421051       NaN -0.031075 -0.031075   1.0 -0.031075 -0.031075       NaN
2018-06-29 14:32:32.964218 -1.065603  0.421051   2.0 -0.322276 -0.644552  1.051223 -0.031075 -0.031075   1.0 -0.031075 -0.031075       NaN
```

Comment: Wow!  Why not do you own rolling?!?!?!  Nice!  +1

Comment: That's how I `roll`